# Druid implementation suggestions for Data analytics platform

Tags: database, database-design, aggregate-functions, druid

I need to make some sort of analytical platform using druid. I would like to ask for community ideas on if druid would be a good fit and some sort of idea for the implementation of such.
I have a system where I receive messages over RabbitMQ. An example message I may get would be the following:

```
session_id: 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-556642440000
type: NORMAL or DLR_INTERIM or DLR (as final)
direction: IN or OUT
customer_id: 1
seizures: 1
units: 1
datetime: 2022-11-08 12:00:00
status: OK
dlr_status: NONE
```

Final table needs to contain all the records with at least following fields (any additional ones you may suggest that will help are totally fine)

```
DateTime InCustomer OutCustomer InSeizures OutSeizures InUnits OutUnits InStatus OutStatus InDlrStatus OutDlrStatus
```

The system works the following way (note that each session id in this process is the same) (also note that all the messages are sent to druid over Kafka):

1. I get IN record with no status and no DLR status. It needs to be
   logged right away somehow
2. I get OUT records until one of them eventually succeeds. Each failed out record needs to be logged. Once I finally get a working out record, I need to "**update**" the IN record, so the last one no longer counts.
3. Now I get DLR INTERIM OUT, so I need to update OutDlrStatus on in again to ENROUTE for example
4. Now I also get DLR INTERIM IN so I update InDrlStatus to ENROUTE for example
5. Now I get DLR OUT, so I update OutDlrStatus to DELIEVERED
6. And now I get DLR IN so I update InDlrStatus to DELIEVERED, for example

See how I say update - so basically if I get two failed records (step 2) and third is successful, I need a query that will return something like this:

```
DateTime InCustomer OutCustomer InSeizures OutSeizures InUnits OutUnits InStatus OutStatus InDlrStatus OutDlrStatus
time     1          3           1          3           1       1        OK       OK        DELIEVERED  DELIEVERED
failed1t 1          1           0          1           0       1        NONE     RSYSERR   NONE        NONE
failed2t 1          2           0          1           0       1        NONE     RSYSERR   NONE        NONE
```

So as far as I understand, there is no "updating" in druid, especially not with Streaming mode. So as far as I understand, I need to probably be just adding new records, but when executing the query, just get the one final one, for that session (or in this case, timeframe), right?

**So what I'm looking for is a way to store and "update" this data in real time and a SQL query that would finally output the result I want (such as the one in the table above).**

I'm not sure if I was able to properly explain everything, but I hope you at least have idea on the requirements, and of course, feel free to ask for any further clarification in comments.